# Find textbox value and attribute if wrapped in span

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, listview, textbox

I have a listview that contains a dropdown, 3 textboxes, 1 textbox wrapped in a span to toggle visiblility and 2 buttons.
I'm having trouble accessing the value and a value of an attribute of the textbox wrapped in the span. It probably has to do with how I'm trying to access it. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the listview:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView1">
<LayoutTemplate>
    <table id="tablesorter" style="border: solid 1px black; width: 55%;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <a href="#">Country</a>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <a href="#">Info.</a>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <a href="#">Action</a>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</LayoutTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<select id="Existing" data="<%# Eval("Type").ToString()%>"
                class="Existing" style="width: 90px">
                <option value="0">USA</option>
                <option value="1">CAN</option>
                <option value="2">MEX</option>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input size="4" data="" type="text" id="city" value="<%# Eval("City")%>" />
            <input size="4" data="" type="text" id="state" value="<%# Eval("State")%>" />
            <input size="4" data="" type="text" id="Phone" value="<%# Eval("PhoneNbr")%>" />
            <span class="ZipBox" id="ZipBox" style="visibility: hidden">
                <input maxlength="5" data="" class="zip" size="5" type="text" id="zip" value="<%# Eval("ZIP")%>" />
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <2 buttons here>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Here is my Javascript where I'm accessing the values of all the textboxes and such on button click...

```
$(.updatebuttonclick)
        .click(function() {
            var parent = $(this).parent().prev();
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');

            var TypeNode = tr.find("select.Existing").first();
            var cityNode = parent.children(".city").first();
            var stateNode = parent.children(".state").first();
            var phoneNode = parent.children(".phone").first();
            var zipNode = parent.children(".zip").first();


            var newcity = cityNode.val();
            var originalcity = cityNode.attr('data');

            var newstate = stateNode.val();
            var originalstate = stateNode.attr('data');

            var newphone = phoneNode.val();
            var originalphone = phoneNode.attr('data');


            //check for business type for extension
            if (newcity == "2") {

                var newzip = zipNode.val();
                var originalzip = zipNode.attr('data');
            }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just access the zipNode by ID:

```
var zipNode = parent.find("#zip");
```

Comment: give to the first responder...Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is it as easy as setting IDs to the text boxes and accessing them via:

```
document.getElementById('yourtextboxid').value
```

or

```
document.yourformname.yourtextboxname.value
```

or

```
$('#yourtextboxid').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use find function to find element deeply in the DOM

```
var zipNode = parent.find(".zip");
```